# Does Angular 4 resolve css variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, webpack

For example:

```
styles: [`
    .selected {
         background-color: var(--selected-hero-background-color, #CFD8DC); }`]
```

If the `--selected-hero-background-color` is provided in the global style sheet will Angular resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Polymer has had support for this for a while, so I'm hoping Angular has similar plans / a module that can be plugged into the build process - perhaps via webpack ...

Comment: I'm also hoping there will be some sort of tree shakeable import mechanism for importing css into a component.  So for example `styles: [@somecsslib/basecomponent1]` where @somecsslib is declared as an npm dependency.